# Why do not MonadTrans the whole type?

Tags: haskell

The MonadTrans type is defined as follow:

```
class MonadTrans t where
  -- | Lift a computation from the argument monad
  -- to the constructed monad.
  lift :: (Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

and looking at the implementation of:

```
instance MonadTrans (ExceptT e) where
  lift = ExceptT . liftM Right
```

The type constructor of `ExceptT` has three type variables:

```
newtype ExceptT e m a =
  ExceptT { runExceptT :: m (Either e a)) }
```

So the type constructor `ExceptT` does not get fully applied with types.
Why it is possible, not to mention all type variables in the instance implementation of `MonadTrans` for `ExceptT e`?

Comment: The _kinds_ of type variables in Haskell classes are inferred from how those variables are used in the class declaration. Here, `t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *` since it needs some `m` and `a` applied to it for it to be a type (and `m :: * -> *` since it needs `a` applied to it for it to be a type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to mention is that `lift` definition uses "point-free" style. It is equivalent to

```
instance MonadTrans (ExceptT e) where
  lift x = ExceptT (liftM Right x)
```

Now to the question. The expression under `instance MonadTrans` is `(ExceptT e)`. This is what substitues `t` in class declaration. Lets substitute it in `lift`s signature:

```
instance MonadTrans (ExceptT e) where
  --                          (this was t)
  --                               ||
  --                               \/
  lift :: (Monad m) => m a ->  ExceptT e   m a
  lift = ExceptT (liftM Right x)
```

In this expression `liftM Right x :: m (Either a b)`, which is exactly what `ExceptT` takes.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you fully apply you are left with an expression that stands for a type, but you want to state things about the type function, in this case of kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`, that is something that takes a monad (`* -> *` + laws) and produces a monad. Any instance of the class is such a *transformer* `t` that given a monad `m` allows you to *lift* values `m a` into values `(t m) a`. How many arguments you fix determines whether you talk about *transformer* (no argument supplied), the *transformed monad* (one argument supplied - the monad you wish the transformer to act on), or a monadic value (both arguments supplied).